# Python:Scraping speech data from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Basically, I want to get all the speeches from mit romney from this link

http://mittromneycentral.com/speeches/

I know how to use BeautifulSoup to get all the urls from the link above.

```
def mywebcrawl(url):
    urls = []
    htmltext = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    #print soup
    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href = True):
        #append url to top level link
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url,tag['href'])
        urls.append(tag['href'])
    pprint(urls)
```

However, for each url, I cannot extract the speech (note I only want the speech only, no irrelevant stuff). I want to build a function that will iterate through the list of urls and extract the speeches. I have used `soup.find_all('table')` and `soup.find_all('font')` but I cannot get the desired results. They failed to extract the entire speech for most times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the strategy I used:

- The speech is contained within `<div class="entry-content">`
- The speech is contained with `<p>` tags that do not have a class attribute. The other `<p>` tags under the `<div>` do have a `class` attribute.

Here is the code for getting the list of speeches and parsing out the speech from a speech's page:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

def get_list_of_speeches(html):
    soup = BS(html)
    content_div = soup.findAll('div', {"class":"entry-content"})[0]
    speech_links = content_div.findAll('a')
    speeches = []
    for speech in speech_links:
        title = speech.text.encode('utf-8')
        link = speech['href']
        speeches.append( (title, link) )
    return speeches

# speeches.htm is http://mittromneycentral.com/speeches/
speech_html = open('speeches.htm').read()
get_list_of_speeches(speech_html):

def get_speech_text(html):
    soup = BS(html)
    content_div = soup.findAll('div', {"class":"entry-content"})[0]
    content = content_div.findAll('p', {"class":None})
    speech = ''
    for paragraph in content:
        speech += paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') + '\n'
    return speech


# file1.html is http://mittromneycentral.com/speeches/2006-speeches/092206-values-voters-summit-2006 
html = open('file1.htm').read()
print get_speech_text(html)
```